# Jquery: Problem on radio buttons?

Tags: jquery

I have some radio buttons with different numeric values. How to apply autoselect option on which radio button value is smaller that other radio button values.

Ex:

```
            <table class="tbl">
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="" value="15" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="" value="45" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="" value="10" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="" value="12" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="radio" name="" value="25" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `apply autoselect option`?

Comment: We need to select a radio button which is having the smallest value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be solved without `each`. Just find index of min value and select this radio button on this index like below.

```
var radios = $(".tbl input:radio");
var vals = radios.map(function(index, el) { return parseInt($(el).val()); }).get();
var index = $.inArray(Math.min.apply(null, vals), vals);

radios.eq(index).attr("checked", "checked");
```

Comment: You avoid using each, but I think the code is a lot less readable because of it.

Comment: @Richard, i agree, but i'd prefer this way

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean select the one with the lowest value automatically then this will do:

```
var lowest;
$(':radio').each(function() {
    if (!lowest || parseInt($(this).val()) < parseInt(lowest.val()))
        lowest = $(this);
});
lowest.attr('checked', 'checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gUnkq/13/

Might be a better way to do it but this works.

Comment: Please check that code in http://jsfiddle.net/gUnkq/, it is not giving proper results.

Comment: It's checking the radiobutton with a value of 10 for me. I don't see how that is not the correct result?

Comment: It doesn't work properly, because you comparing strings, not int (apply `parseInt`)

Comment: I changed it to do parseInt after his comment, but it was still working correctly for me before (in chrome and firefox)

Comment: lol, I see. Funny that his example values just happened to work. Thanks for pointing that out.